# Why is nginx slower than apache for reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, performance, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

Everywhere i read that nginx is much faster than apache and specially as a reverse proxy.
For me its quite opposite, and i cannot determine why. Am i doing it wrong?

For a simple request, with apache i get a time of **45ms** with nginx its **80ms**. Nearly double the time.

Checked with browser and "ab -n1000 -c5 https://myddomain.de"

Apache 2.4.10

Nginx 1.9.10

Relevant apache config parts:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mydomain.de
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        ProxyPass / https://myipaddress:8443/prod/public/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://myipaddress:8443/prod/public/

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /blablcert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /blablaprivkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Nginx config:

```
server {

        # SSL configuration
        #
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate           /blablacert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key       /blablaprivkey.pem;
        ssl_dhparam  /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
        ssl on;

        server_name mydomain.de;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass      https://myipaddress:8443/prod/public/;
                proxy_read_timeout      90;
        }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this sort of question is likely to illicit more opinion based comments rather than facts. My experience of these sorts of issues is that when one finds a huge difference then it is normally a setup/configuration issue or the use of an older version with the one that is running slower.

Comment: As @Unbeliever says httpd is not slower than nginx, no matter what all the misinformation and crud people say out of ignorance. It just depends on how you configure them both. If configured properly and similarily there shouldn't be much difference between each in most cases. For your specific case, check the ciphers available "SSLCipherSuite" is the same for both and also SSLProtocols

Comment: This could be due to nginx not keeping the connections to proxy on between requests. You might want to look at nginx upstream keepalive options.

Comment: I tried the keepalive option: No success.
I have adapted the ciphers: No success.

Comment: Does this happen for static files as well as dynamic? If nginx and Apache are running on the same server, as a test, try serving the files directly from nginx. If they are on different servers, I would start troublehooting the network between the two servers.

Comment: The network is the same, because i tried the apache and the nginx as proxy on the same machine. The apache behind the proxy was always the same.

Comment: You could try wire sniffing it...